# Prometheus-server: Appending scrape report failed" err="write to WAL: log samples: write /data/wal/00007153: read-only file system"

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I have Prometheus 4.x running on my Kubernetes cluster, All my metrics were unable to retrive since error below:

```
level=warn ts=2021-11-29T08:43:50.103Z caller=scrape.go:945 component="scrape manager" scrape_pool=kubernetes-service-endpoints target=http://10.0.10.4:9100/metrics msg="appending scrape report failed" err="write to WAL: log samples: write /data/wal/00007153: read-only file system"
```

I am unable to create new file under `/data/wal` as well which returns "read-only file system"

Any idea of why does it happen?

Comment: Something happened on the node and whatever filesystem is mounted to `/data` is now read-only. Try `kubectl exec`-ing into the Pod and see the status of mounts with `mount`. Possibly `dmesg` can tell you why the mount was made read-only.

Comment: After checking dmesg on the host os, there is some abnormal output which is hard to read. anyway, this issue was solved by pod restart. thanks.